# Parsing unicode input using python json.loads

Tags: python, django, json, unicode

What is the best way to load JSON Strings in Python?

I want to use json.loads to process unicode like this:

```
import json
json.loads(unicode_string_to_load)
```

I also tried supplying 'encoding' parameter with value 'utf-16', but the error did not go away.

Full SSCCE with error:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
value = '{"foo" : "bar"}'
print(json.loads(value)['foo'])     #This is correct, prints 'bar'

some_unicode = unicode("degradé")  
#last character is latin e with acute "\xe3\xa9"
value = '{"foo" : "' + some_unicode + '"}'
print(json.loads(value)['foo'])            #incorrect, throws error
```

Error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 
6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Do you have any source data that shows the problem?

Comment: I get this error.

(UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf16' codec can't decode byte 0x38 in position 6: truncated data)

I use this command: json.loads(response, encoding='utf-16'). Sequencly this error comes for many unicode characters...

Comment: ..... I think we need to have a little discussion as to what "source data" means...

Comment: Source data is huge unicode encoded string which i can't past it here...,

Comment: Then paste *some* of it. Something for us to go on...

Comment: Encoding keeps on changing and at difficult to identify, is there any encoding type which is universal and works for all characters?

Comment: Here it is... '{"successful":true, "data":[76,{"posting_id":"1753178","site_tender_id":"3188446'

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf16' codec can't decode byte 0x38 in position 6: truncated data

Answer (score 12):

I typecasting the string into unicode string using 'latin-1' fixed the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf16' codec can't decode byte 0x38 in 
position 6: truncated data
```

Fixed code:

```
import json

ustr_to_load = unicode(str_to_load, 'latin-1')

json.loads(ustr_to_load)
```

And then the error is not thrown.

Comment: BTW, `latin-1` is the old name for `iso-8859-1` and these days you're much more likely to see `iso-8859-15` -- the only difference is that the latter includes the Euro sign.  If you decode with `-1` and the string was encoded with `-15` it will mostly be OK but Euro signs will look very peculiar when you print or show them.

Answer (score 6):

The OP clarifies (in a comment!)...:

> Source data is huge unicode encoded
>   string

Then you have to know **which** of the many unicode encodings it uses -- clearly not 'utf-16', since that failed, but there are so many others -- 'utf-8', 'iso-8859-15', and so forth.  You either try them all until one works, or `print repr(str_to_load[:80])` and paste what it shows as an edit of your question, so we can guess on your behalf!-).

Comment: It is difficult to identify particular encoding during load because source data may contain characters from various languages of the world.
Is there any way to detect encoding type?

Comment: str_to_load keeps on changing, utf-8 worked for some, utf-32 worked for some... but how do I auto detect it?

Comment: That string is '{"successful":true, "data":[76,{"posting_id":"1753178","site_tender_id":"3188446'

Comment: To try and guess the encoding of a byte string -- try http://chardet.feedparser.org/ .  The string you show is ASCII (which is also valid utf-8 by definition, and also valid iso-8859-1, etc: ASCII is the common subset of most encodings!) so it's impossible to guess what potential non-ASCII encoding it might be in. UnicodeDecodeError messages carry the exact index of the first problematic byte, so show the repr of the 80-long byte string centered on that index when you do get an error.

Comment: When I read the entire string, I found unicode characters, have a look at it in the next string...
"Lucaya, Grand Bahama; 4 Bedroom, 3 \xbd Bathroom"

Comment: The encoding of the string depends where you got it from. That string is probably one of ISO-8859-1 or Windows code page 1252. If your string is coming from a form submission from a web page, it will be in the same encoding as that web page. You really want to be using UTF-8 if you have any say in the matter. You can also avoid all charset problems by getting the JSON encoder to write non-ASCII commands using the JavaScipt `\u` escape; Python's `json.dump` does this by default but JavaScript's `JSON.stringify` does not.

Comment: `\xbd` in ISO-8859-x for several values of x (and other encodings such as CP-1252) is the single character representing the fraction `1/2` so your encoding's likely to be among this group.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way I have found is

```
import simplejson as json
```

that way your code remains the same

```
json.loads(str_to_load)
```

reference: https://simplejson.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

With django you can use SimpleJSON and use loads instead of just load.

```
from django.utils import simplejson

simplejson.loads(str_to_load, "utf-8")
```

Comment: this no longer works in django as it uses the default that comes with python