# Python JSON decoder error with unicode characters in request content

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Using requests library to execute http GET that return JSON response i'm getting this error when response string contains unicode char:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid control character at: line 1 column 20 (char 19)
```

Execute same http request with Postman the json output is:

```
{ "value": "VILLE D\u0019ANAUNIA" }
```

My python code is:

```
data = requests.get(uri, headers=HEADERS).text
json_data = json.loads(data)
```

Can I remove or replace all Unicode chars before executing conversion with json.loads(...)?

Comment: see if this one helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15321138/removing-unicode-u2026-like-characters-in-a-string-in-python2-7 
or
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234228/parsing-unicode-input-using-python-json-loads

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27955978/python-requests-url-with-unicode-parameters

Comment: What is the raw response content (`print(requests.get(uri, headers=HEADERS).content)`)? It could be caused by an encoding problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely to be caused by a RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK U+2019 (`’`). For reasons I cannot guess, the high order byte has been dropped leaving you with a control character which should be escaped in a correct JSON string.

So the correct way would be to control what exactly the API returns. If id does return a `'\u0019'` control character, you should contact the API owner because the problem should be there.

As a workaround, you can try to limit the problem for your processing by filtering out non ascii or control characters:

```
data = requests.get(uri, headers=HEADERS).text
data = ''.join((i for i in data if 0x20 <= ord(i) < 127))  # filter out unwanted chars
json_data = json.loads(data)
```

You should get `{'value': 'VILLE DANAUNIA'}`

Alternatively, you can replace all unwanted characters with spaces:

```
data = requests.get(uri, headers=HEADERS).text
data = ''.join((i if 0x20 <= ord(i) < 127 else ' ' for i in data))
json_data = json.loads(data)
```

You would get `{'value': 'VILLE D ANAUNIA'}`

Comment: Thank's for suggestion! For now i don't need replace unicode chars but maybe it could be useful in the future!

Answer (score 2):

The code below works on python 2.7:

```
import json
d = json.loads('{ "value": "VILLE D\u0019ANAUNIA" }')
print(d)
```

The code below works on python 3.7:

```
import json
d = json.loads('{ "value": "VILLE D\u0019ANAUNIA" }', strict=False)
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{u'value': u'VILLE D\x19ANAUNIA'}
```

Another point is that requests get return the data as json:

```
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')
r.json()
```

Comment: With parameter strict=False no exception was throwed! Thank's