# Call Python script per PowerShell & passing PSObject and return the parsed data

Tags: python, powershell, spacy, psobject

some background: currently I am querying 4Mio rows (with 50 columns) from a MS SQL server with [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/) into a PSObject (in Batch 10.000 rows each query), processing the data with PowerShell (a lot of RegEx stuff) and writing back into a MariaDb with [SimplySql](https://github.com/mithrandyr/SimplySql).
In average i get approx. 150 rows/sec. Had to use a lot of tricks (Net's Stringbuilder etc.) for this performance, its not that bad imho

As new requirements I want to detect the language of some text cells and I have to remove personal data (name & address). I found some good python libs ([spacy](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#named-entities) and [pycld2](https://github.com/aboSamoor/pycld2)) for that purpose.
I made tests with pycld2 - pretty good detection.

Simplified code for clarification (hint:I am a python noob):

```
#get data from MS SQL
$data = Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance $Connection -Query $Query -As PSObject -QueryTimeout 1800
for ($i=0;$i -lt $data.length;$i++){
  #do a lot of other stuff here
  #...
  #finally make lang detection
  if ($LangDetect.IsPresent){
    $strLang = $tCaseDescription -replace "([^\p{L}\p{N}_\.\s]|`t|`n|`r)+",""
    $arg = "import pycld2 as cld2; isReliable, textBytesFound, details = cld2.detect('" + $strLang + "', isPlainText = True, bestEffort = True);print(details[0][1])"
    $tCaseLang = & $Env:Programfiles\Python39\python.exe -c $arg
  } else {
    $tCaseLang = ''
  }
}
#write to MariaDB
Invoke-SqlUpdate -ConnectionName $ConnectionName -Query $Query
```

This python call each time works, but it destroys the performance (12rows/sec) due the loop-call and importing pycld2 lib each time. So, this is a lame solution :)
In addition, as mentioned above - I want to use spacy - where some more columns has to parsed for getting rid of the personal data.

I am not sure, if I have the mood to convert the whole PS Parser to python :|

I believe, a better solution might be to pass the whole PSObject from PowerShell to python (before the PS loop starts) and return it as well as PSObject - after it has been processed in python - but I don't know, how I can realize this with python / python function.

What would be your approach/suggestions, any other ideas?
Thanks :)

Comment: It may actually be faster just to do the text removal with Powershell?

Comment: I already do a lot of parsing, removals etc. with Powershell. Removing emails with powershell is easy as well. But I did not find any data science library as like spacy for detection of names or detection of language as like with pycld2. That is the reason for Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following simplified example shows you how you can pass multiple `[pscustomobject]` (`[psobject]`) instances from PowerShell to a Python script (passed as a string via `-c` in this case):

- by **using JSON** as the serialization format, via [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json)...
- ... and passing that JSON **via the *pipeline***, which **Python can read via *stdin*** (standard input).

**Important**:

- **Character encoding**:

  - PowerShell uses the encoding specified in the `$OutputEncoding` preference variable when sending data to *external programs* (such as Python), which commendably defaults to BOM-less UTF-8 in *PowerShell [Core] v6+*, but regrettably to ASCII(!) in *Windows PowerShell*.
  - Just like PowerShell limits you to sending *text* to an external program, it also invariably interprets what it *receives* as text, namely based on the encoding stored in `[Console]::OutputEncoding`; regrettably, *both* PowerShell editions as of this writing default to the system's *OEM* code page.
  - **To both send and receive (BOM-less) UTF-8 in both PowerShell editions**, (temporarily) set `$OutputEncoding` and `[Console]::OutputEncoding` as follows:
    `$OutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Utf8Encoding]::new($false)`
- If you want your Python script **to also *output* objects, again consider using *JSON***, which on the PowerShell you can parse into objects with **[`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json)**.

```
# Sample input objects.
$data = [pscustomobject] @{ one = 1; two = 2 }, [pscustomobject] @{ one = 10; two = 20 }

# Convert to JSON and pipe to Python.
ConvertTo-Json $data | python -c @'

import sys, json

# Parse the JSON passed via stdin into a list of dictionaries.
dicts = json.load(sys.stdin)

# Sample processing: print the 'one' entry of each dict.
for dict in dicts:
  print(dict['one'])

'@
```

---

If the data to pass is a collection of single-line *strings*, you don't need JSON:

```
$data = 'foo', 'bar', 'baz'

$data | python -c @'

import sys

# Sample processing: print each stdin input line enclosed in [...]
for line in sys.stdin:
  print('[' + line.rstrip('\r\n') + ']')

'@
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the @mklement0's answer, i want to share the completed and tested solution with returning the JSON from python to Powershell with consideration of correct character encoding.
I tried it already with 100k Rows on one batch - no issues, running flawlessly and superfast :)

```
#get data from MS SQL
$query = -join@(
                'SELECT `Id`, `CaseSubject`, `CaseDescription`, 
                `AccountCountry`, `CaseLang` '
                'FROM `db`.`table_global` '
                'ORDER BY `Id` DESC, `Id` ASC '
                'LIMIT 10000;'
                )
$data = Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance $Connection -Query $Query -As PSObject -QueryTimeout 1800

$arg = @'
import pycld2 as cld2
import simplejson as json
import sys, re, logging

def main():
  #toggle the logging level to stderr
  # https://stackoverflow.com/a/6579522/14226613 -> https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.debug
  logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr, level=logging.DEBUG)
  logging.info('->Encoding Python: ' + str(sys.stdin.encoding))
  # consideration of correct character encoding -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/30107752/14226613
  # Parse the JSON passed via stdin into a list of dictionaries -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/65051178/14226613
  cases = json.load(sys.stdin, 'utf-8')
  # Sample processing: print the 'one' entry of each dict.
  # https://regex101.com/r/bymIQS/1
  regex = re.compile(r'(?=[^\w\s]).|[\r\n]|\'|\"|\\')
  # hash table with Country vs Language for 'boosting' the language detection, if pycld2 is not sure
  lang_country = {'Albania' : 'ALBANIAN', 'Algeria' : 'ARABIC', 'Argentina' : 'SPANISH', 'Armenia' : 'ARMENIAN', 'Austria' : 'GERMAN', 'Azerbaijan' : 'AZERBAIJANI', 'Bangladesh' : 'BENGALI', 'Belgium' : 'DUTCH', 'Benin' : 'FRENCH', 'Bolivia, Plurinational State of' : 'SPANISH', 'Bosnia and Herzegovina' : 'BOSNIAN', 'Brazil' : 'PORTUGUESE', 'Bulgaria' : 'BULGARIAN', 'Chile' : 'SPANISH', 'China' : 'Chinese', 'Colombia' : 'SPANISH', 'Costa Rica' : 'SPANISH', 'Croatia' : 'CROATIAN', 'Czech Republic' : 'CZECH', 'Denmark' : 'DANISH', 'Ecuador' : 'SPANISH', 'Egypt' : 'ARABIC', 'El Salvador' : 'SPANISH', 'Finland' : 'FINNISH', 'France' : 'FRENCH', 'Germany' : 'GERMAN', 'Greece' : 'GREEK', 'Greenland' : 'GREENLANDIC', 'Hungary' : 'HUNGARIAN', 'Iceland' : 'ICELANDIC', 'India' : 'HINDI', 'Iran' : 'PERSIAN', 'Iraq' : 'ARABIC', 'Ireland' : 'ENGLISH', 'Israel' : 'HEBREW', 'Italy' : 'ITALIAN', 'Japan' : 'Japanese', 'Kosovo' : 'ALBANIAN', 'Kuwait' : 'ARABIC', 'Mexico' : 'SPANISH', 'Monaco' : 'FRENCH', 'Morocco' : 'ARABIC', 'Netherlands' : 'DUTCH', 'New Zealand' : 'ENGLISH', 'Norway' : 'NORWEGIAN', 'Panama' : 'SPANISH', 'Paraguay' : 'SPANISH', 'Peru' : 'SPANISH', 'Poland' : 'POLISH', 'Portugal' : 'PORTUGUESE', 'Qatar' : 'ARABIC', 'Romania' : 'ROMANIAN', 'Russia' : 'RUSSIAN', 'San Marino' : 'ITALIAN', 'Saudi Arabia' : 'ARABIC', 'Serbia' : 'SERBIAN', 'Slovakia' : 'SLOVAK', 'Slovenia' : 'SLOVENIAN', 'South Africa' : 'AFRIKAANS', 'South Korea' : 'Korean', 'Spain' : 'SPANISH', 'Sweden' : 'SWEDISH', 'Switzerland' : 'GERMAN', 'Thailand' : 'THAI', 'Tunisia' : 'ARABIC', 'Turkey' : 'TURKISH', 'Ukraine' : 'UKRAINIAN', 'United Arab Emirates' : 'ARABIC', 'United Kingdom' : 'ENGLISH', 'United States' : 'ENGLISH', 'Uruguay' : 'SPANISH', 'Uzbekistan' : 'UZBEK', 'Venezuela' : 'SPANISH'}
  for case in cases:
    #concatenate two fiels and clean them a bitfield, so that we not get any faults due line brakes etc.
    tCaseDescription = regex.sub('', (case['CaseSubject'] + ' ' + case['CaseDescription']))
    tCaseAccCountry = case['AccountCountry']
    if tCaseAccCountry in lang_country:
      language = lang_country[tCaseAccCountry]
      isReliable, textBytesFound, details = cld2.detect(tCaseDescription, 
            isPlainText = True, 
            bestEffort = True,
            hintLanguage = language)
    else:
      isReliable, textBytesFound, details = cld2.detect(tCaseDescription, 
            isPlainText = True, 
            bestEffort = True)

    #Take Value
    case['CaseLang'] = details[0][0]
    #logging.info('->Python processing CaseID: ' + str(case['Id']) + ' / Detected Language: ' + str(case['CaseLang']))
  #encode to JSON
  retVal = json.dumps(cases, 'utf-8')
  return retVal

if __name__ == '__main__':
  retVal = main()
  sys.stdout.write(str(retVal))
'@

$dataJson = ConvertTo-Json $data
$data = ($dataJson | python -X utf8 -c $arg) | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach($case in $data) {
    $tCaseSubject = $case.CaseSubject -replace "\\", "\\" -replace "'", "\'"
    $tCaseDescription = $case.CaseDescription -replace "\\", "\\" -replace "'", "\'"
    $tCaseLang = $case.CaseLang.substring(0,1).toupper() + $case.CaseLang.substring(1).tolower()
    $tCaseId = $case.Id
    
    $qUpdate = -join @(
        "UPDATE db.table_global SET CaseSubject=`'$tCaseSubject`', "
        "CaseDescription=`'$tCaseDescription`', "
        "CaseLang=`'$tCaseLang`' "
        "WHERE Id=$tCaseId;"
    )

    try{
        $result = Invoke-SqlUpdate -ConnectionName 'maria' -Query $qUpdate
      } catch {
        Write-Host -Foreground Red -Background Black ("result: " + $result + ' / No. ' + $i)
        #break
      }
}

Close-SqlConnection -ConnectionName 'maria'
```

Please apologize the unfortunate syntax highlighting; script block contains SQL, Powershell and Python..